# JQuery’s $(document).ready is not always being called, is it a known issue?

Tags: jquery

I am testing my script in IE9. I noticed that $(document).ready is not always being called. That means 1 out of 8 times the function referred by $(document).ready is not being called.

As soon as I move the $(document).ready call to the end of the document, it works perfectly. The problem arises only if I move the $(document).ready call to the  section.

I read through the blog post that confirms this problem in IE6: 
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/08/bug-153-self-closing-script-tag-issues.html

Considering the reputation of JQuery, I am surprised by the issue. Is this a known issue/bug and workaround for JQuery? Or am I missing anything?

Thank you,

UPDATE:

I just wanted to update with regards to this issue:

The script was working fine on the other browsers (Chrome and FF), only my dev machine's IE was problematic. Once I reset IE (reset and restore on the IS settings’ advanced tab)  $(document).ready started to work as expected. So I know the solution, but I like to know the root cause.

While I am disappointed on IE’s shaky behavior, this case is left with an unanswered question:
One of IE’s setting changes the way that $(document).ready behaves, and it causes the problem I explained in this post. Does anybody know which setting cased this issue?

Comment: If this is the self-closing script issue, just close the script properly; this is then obviously a bug in IE, not jQuery...

Comment: I've never had an issue with `$(document).ready`.  Can you show us your code?  Methinks something else is the problem.

Comment: make sure the jQuery script is done loading before the `$(document).ready` is executed, or `$` will be undefined and it won't run

Comment: I've designed 3 large programs in the last year, one of which runs on SharePoint, all cross browser compat with IE7-9, Chrome, FF, Safari, and Opera, and I've ***NEVER*** seen the issue you are referring too? Can we see your example?

Comment: Self-closing script tags are invalid HTML, and I'm pretty sure they don't work in any browser.  It's not a bug, it's how HTML works.

Comment: Also, just to note, if you're using a new version of jQuery (1.6+) you don't have to write that long old line anymore, replace it with `$(function() { /* do jQuery Work */ })`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be using jQuery 1.8.0.

jQuery 1.8.0 introduced a bug that caused the ready method to fire too early in IE9.

The bug was fixed in 1.8.1, and is still fixed in 1.8.2. Upgrading to either of those two versions should fix that problem if you are currently using 1.8.0.

The bug was mentioned in the release notes for 1.8.1 http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/

Here's the ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282

Comment: And where is the documentation of this "bug", because I've yet to see the problem and am trying to force it now, using 1.8!

Comment: Hi Kevin B, I am using jquery-ui-1.8.23.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reproduce this issue.  The issue is sporadic.  I'm using a datatable and jquery version jquery-1.10.2.  I've confirmed the ready event isn't being fired. 
To reproduce, an IE page opens a target window name via a link.
e.g.
        go to page#2

Clicking the link opens a new tab that contains a page with a datatable.  I'll call this  new page page#2 and the one that called it page#1.  I don't close page#2.  I go back to page#1 and click the link again.  If I toggle between the tabs (page#1 and page#2), I'm able to see about 1 out of every 4 tries that page#2 does not render with the datatable (just the table).  In addition, the lower left hand corener of the browser window shows that yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: My bad...  Looks like IE has no tolerance for 2 $(document).ready(function() {}  ... I had 2 of these in my code.  One on the page and one from an include